# Eclipse change breakpoint color

Tags: eclipse, colors, breakpoints

I am using eclipse luna. In my color scheme (and tbh in the default one as well) breakpoints are barelly visible.

[image]

I found the option to change the text behaviour at a certain breakpoint (for example highlight) but I cannot find anywhere to change the breapoint color itself, so it can be RED like in every other IDE. I would aprichiate any help!

Comment: did you ever find a fix?

Comment: No... I stopped using dark theme in eclipse because its not fully working

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is not possible to change the breakpoint color by merely changing an Eclipse setting. Displayed breakpoint is actually a png image called `brkp_obj.png` placed inside some subdirectory of `org.eclipse.osgi` directory of Eclipse installation. For me it's inside the `C:\Program Files\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\1375\0\.cp\icons\full\obj16` but search for the file on your system for the exact location.
If you wish to change breakpoint's color one possible way is to edit its color in that png file using some image editing application.