# How to improve the Icon-visibility of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jvm

I want to change the icon-Size and colour of the breakpoint in eclipse.

In my eclipse it is all so tiny, but especially the breakpoint is hard to see.
(I run eclipse Version (4.20.0) under XUbuntu on a JVM, which runs on my Win10 machine, so far to the environment)
The resulution of my display (1080x 1920 FullHD), this high resolution might be rootcause for tiny icons, but changing my monitior can't be an option.

I was already able the set the font-size to a normal level, but upscaling everything with:

`-Dswt.autoScale=150` (which would affect the icons too),

in the .init-file of the eclipse-installation-folder, but that ruins the allingment of the eclipse-panels for me. (see the picture [Alingment messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtKVL.png))

advanced settigns like:

```
-Dswt.enable.autoScale=true
-Dswt.autoScale=150
-Dswt.autoScale.method=nearest
```

in the .init-file also doesn't work for me.

I tried to fix it by the solution in the link below (generate a new + bigger icon-image), but i can't find the right folder, where to change the breakpoint-icon manualy (there are too many subsubsub-folders with tiny icon-images in it).

[Eclipse change breakpoint color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835260/eclipse-change-breakpoint-color)

I tried to use $grip in order to search after the filename-pattern (brkp_obj.png) in the installation folder of eclipse
, /home/USERNAME/eclipse/java-2021-06/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/,
but I am not sure if they might have changed the filename of the breakpoint-image since the post in the link...

So is there any (easy) solution to improve the visibility of this tiny breakpoint-icon..or all icons at once?
(permanently not by Alt + mousewheel)
And if there is no easy solution, where can I find a list of icon-filenames for my eclipse-version Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0) in order to change the breakboint-icon on my own?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do your OS settings match what you want and font and icons are only too small in Eclipse? If yes and only if yes, you should use the environment variable `GDK_DPI_SCALE` for Eclipse. Only if that doesn't work, use as only argument `-Dswt.autoScale=200` for double size icons (`-Dswt.autoScale=150` does affect only the font size, but does not affect the icons since 150 is rounded down to 100): https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#swt-autoscale-tweaks See also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48474802/6505250

Comment: @howlger I checked the Dispay-Settings of the OS its 1080x1920 and the settings of the JVM (1080 x1920, 100% unscaled) as well. Preinstalled Programs as libre Office Calc have suitable icons with approximately 2 times the size. I consequently tried the 'GDK_DPI_SCALE=1.5 ./eclipse' but it only affects the fonsize... as well I tried `-Dswt.autoScale=200`which causes a chrash of the alingment (as in the picture I attaced in my question-post) And one thing I wanted to mention with nearest you can set zoom-persentage which does not have to be a multiple of 100% :-) e.g. 
`-Dswt.autoScale=150`

Comment: But as shown in the picture I attached in my  root-question, even the slight increase of the autoscale-size causes total misalingment of the eclipse-panels

Comment: Please try `GDK_DPI_SCALE=1.75` and `GDK_DPI_SCALE=2.0` without any `-Dswt...` and tell the results by 3 screenshots (default, 1.75 and 2.0). The documentation says that `nearest` is about interpolation, not about rounding of the icon size.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide the documentation of the two latest changes (default settings, 'DK_DPI_SCALE=1.75' and 'GDK_DPI_SCALE=2.0') which I tried:

[default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRqNV.png)

[DK_DPI_SCALE=1.75](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4y76X.png)

[GDK_DPI_SCALE=2.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZdHP.png)

Summery of the results: no improvement of the iconsize, but of the font-size.